# can't interact (in game view) with objects displayed by secondary camera - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have two cameras that occupy different spaces in the Game view. The problem is that I can interact with my object shown by the main camera, but when I move this object (in scene view) to make it appear in the visual field of the second camera, the object is displayed in Game view but I can't interact with it (the object is a scroll Rect btw) through Game view. Seems to have a very simple solution but I couldn't find it.

Here are the parameters of both cameras: 
Main Camera:
[image: main camera]
[image: secondary camera]
  [image: can scroll]

[image: can't scroll]

Comment: The screenshot of your second camera looks identical to your first one.  Did you post the correct screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry, should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can only interact with the current MainCamera in Unity.
If you could explain what you're trying to achieve with 2 cameras maybe we can help you find a better solution.